# Is extension of continuous function on $\Bbb Q$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\Bbb Q \to  \Bbb Q$ is a continuous function then $f$ can be extented to $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $g$ is continuous

Is it true?

Comment: In general, $f$ needs to be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$, but the more specific condition could be considered "cauchy continuity" that is, cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ must map to a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ under $f$

Comment: @rubikscube09 No, $f$ need not be uniformly continuous on $\Bbb Q$; the function $f(x)=x^2$ certainly extends to a continuous function on $\Bbb R$. A continuous function from $\Bbb Q$ to  $\Bbb R$ extends continuously to  $\Bbb R$ if and only if  its restriction  to every bounded subset of  $\Bbb Q$ is uniformly continuous

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What if$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<\sqrt2\\1&\text{ if }x>\sqrt2?\end{cases}$$

Comment: Not that there's any problem with that example, but I bet $1/(x^2-2)$ would be clearer to some readers, one in particular...

Comment: Nice! I would have posted it if I had had that idea.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f_{\Bbb Q}: \Bbb Q\to \Bbb R$ (including funcitons that are $\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$) can be extended to a continuous function $f_{\Bbb R}:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ iff it is *sequentially continuous*. In other words, if for any real number $r$ and sequences $x_n, y_n$ of rational numbers with $x_n, y_n\to r$, we have $f(x_n) - f(y_n) \to 0$.